# How to make every logo visually the same size?

Tags: css, height, width

I am struggling with a small piece of code in a Next.js app - but its just a simple CSS issue and I can't quite figure it out.

In the image below, you can see that I have a list of sponsor logos. however, the 3rd and 2nd to last one is significantly smaller (visually). Right now I am just using height and width, I've tried to use max and min height, but that didn't work out at all.

[image]

Can someone plz tell me or link me to a reference that will show me how I can make these logos larger, and the last one smaller?

```
const Banner = () => {
return (
{sponsors.map((sponsor, index) => (
                <Col key={index}>
                    <Link href={`/sponsoren#${sponsor.slug}`}>
                        <a>
                            <img src={sponsor.logo.light} width='auto' height={32} />
                        </a>
                    </Link>
                </Col>
            ))}
)
}
```

I've tried wrapping the whole thing in a div and giving that div a height, then setting the heigt and width of img to auto... didn't work out.

Also if I just manipulate the width, the aspect ratio is incredibly distorted.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I have figured it out!

Just for reference if anyone needs it.

```
.image {
    display: block;
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 90px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

making it display:block and a combo of (max)/(min)-height/width made it work.

Now I just imported the styles sheet and made the `className={styles.image}`